# Typescript warning "Use an interface instead of a type literal"

Tags: typescript, interface

Linting my code, I get this TS warning on `InternalStateType` definition

```
 [line 8]    export type InternalStateType = {
              [key: string]: any,
              appName: string,
              darkMode: boolean,
              defaultLang: string,
              topnavTitle: string,
              messagePanelOpen: boolean,
              sidenavOpen: boolean,
              sidenavMode: string,
              sidenavCollapse: boolean,
              pageFullscreen: boolean,
              pageFooter: boolean,
              initial: boolean,
            };
```

`InternalStateType` is used in my App service

```
/**
 * App service
 */
@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  // Set your states default value.
  private state: InternalStateType = {
    appName: 'MyApp',
    darkMode: false,
    defaultLang: 'en',
    topnavTitle: 'MyApp',
    messagePanelOpen: false,
    sidenavOpen: false,
    sidenavMode: 'over',
    sidenavCollapse: true,
    pageFullscreen: false,
    pageFooter: false,
    initial: false,
  };
```

Does it mean that it should be better to replace:

```
export type InternalStateType = {
```

with:

```
export interface InternalStateType {
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, that's the case.

There's no reason to make InternalStateType a class here over an interface, since it has no behaviour of it's own - it's just a DTO-type thing.

Answer (score 10):

To whom that might care, it should be

```
export interface InternalStateType {
```

without the equal sign.

Here are the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).